# String keeps getting reset to null

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I'm writing this code that should let me add an student to a fictional DB, everything is working fine but the `setMail`.

If I run the code from main, when I reach the mail section, after I write mail and select mail service (@gmail, @hotmail, etc) and I press aceptar, it should concat the username and the mailservice, but instead, it will get a null string.

If I run only the `JPane` it works fine. I even `setMail` (which belongs to RegistroEstudiante.java) from Correos.java.

But if I run it from RegistroEstudiante.java the string is always null.

Basic testing via Console: Both should be the same

```
Print from Correos.java: rere@gmail.com
Print from RegistroEstudiante.java: null
```

---

```
package escuela;
import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.*;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;

public class Estudiante {

public static void main(String[] args) {
RegistroEstudiante estudiante = new RegistroEstudiante();

    estudiante.inicio();
}


}
```

---

```
package escuela;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;

public class RegistroEstudiante{

private int matricula = 0; //Sólo 6 dígitos
private byte edad = 0; //No menor de 0
private float altura = 0.0F;
private String nombre = null, menu = null, ape_paterno = null, ape_materno = null, correo = null, genero = null, estadoCivil;
private int length = 0;
private boolean error = false;

public void inicio() {
    String[] menuPrincipal  = { "Ingresar", "Mostrar", "Salir" };
    String[] genero             = { "Masculino", "Femenino" };
    String[] estadoCivilMenu    = { "Soltero/a", "Comprometido/a", "Casado/a", "Divorciado/a", "Viudo/a" };
    Correos Correos = new Correos();
    do {
        try {
            setMenu((String)JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "¿Qué deseas hacer?", "UNACAR", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, menuPrincipal, menuPrincipal[0]));

    switch(getMenu()) {
    case "Ingresar":
        do{
            setError(false);
        try {
            setMatricula(Integer.parseInt((String)JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Introduce Matrícula [6]", "Agregando estudiante", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, null, null)));
        } catch (java.lang.NumberFormatException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Introdujiste un caractér inválido", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE, null);
            setError(true);
        }       
        length = (int)(Math.log10(getMatricula())+1); // Saca cantidad de caracteres
        if ( (length != 6) && (error == false) )
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "La Matrícula DEBE ser de 6 dígitos", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE, null);
            setMatricula(0);
        }
            } while (length != 6);

        //SET NOMBRE
        do{
            setError(false);
            setNombre((String)JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Introduce nombre del alumno", "Agregando estudiante", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, null, null));
            if(StringUtils.isAlpha(getNombre()) == false)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El nombre debe contener únicamente letras [A-Za-z]", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE, null);
                setNombre(null);
                setError(true);
            }

        }while(isError() == true);

        //SET APELLIDO PATERNO
        do{
            setError(false);
            setApe_paterno((String)JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Introduce apellido paterno de " + getNombre(), "Agregando estudiante", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, null, null));
            if(StringUtils.isAlpha(getApe_paterno()) == false)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El apellido debe contener únicamente letras [A-Za-z]", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE, null);
                setApe_paterno(null);
                setError(true);
            }

        }while(isError() == true);

        //SET APellido MATERNO FTW

        do{
            setError(false);
            setApe_materno((String)JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Introduce apellido materno de " + getNombre(), "Agregando estudiante", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, null, null));
            if(StringUtils.isAlpha(getApe_materno()) == false)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El nombre debe contener únicamente letras [A-Za-z]", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE, null);
                setApe_materno(null);
                setError(true);
            }

        }while(isError() == true);

        // SELECCIONA SEXO

        if(JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "Selecciona género de " + getNombre(), "Agregando estudiante", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, genero, genero[0]) == 0 ){
            setGenero("Masculino");
        }else{
                setGenero("Femenino");
        }

        // SET ESTADO CIVIL COMPA

        setEstadoCivil((String)JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Estado Civil de " + getNombre(), "UNACAR", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, estadoCivilMenu, estadoCivilMenu[0]));

        // SET EDAD
        do{
            setError(false);
            try {
                setEdad(Byte.parseByte((String)JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Introduce la edad del alumno", "Agregando estudiante", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, null, null)));
            } catch (java.lang.NumberFormatException e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Aquí no se aceptan números...", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE, null);
                setError(true);
            }
            if(getEdad() < 0)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, getNombre() + " no puede tener 0 años o menos, corrige... ", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE, null);
                setEdad((byte) 0);
                setError(true);
            }

        }while(isError() == true);


        //SET ALTURA

        do{
            setError(false);
            try {
                setAltura(Float.parseFloat((String)JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Introduce la altura del alumno", "Agregando estudiante", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, null, null)));
            } catch (java.lang.NumberFormatException e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Aquí no se aceptan letras...", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE, null);
                setError(true);
            }

            if(getAltura() < 0)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, getNombre() + " no puede medir 0 centimetros o menos, corrige...", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE, null);
                setAltura(0.0F);
                setError(true);
            }

        }while(isError() == true);

        // SetMail
        escuela.Correos.main();

        do {
            try {
            //  setCorreo(correos.getCorreoConcatenado());
                System.out.println("En RegistroEstudiante.java " + correo);
                Thread.sleep(1000);

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } while (correo == null);
        break;

    case "Mostrar":
        break;


        } // END SWITCH
    }// END TRY
    catch (java.lang.NullPointerException e) {
        switch(JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "¿Seguro que deseas salir?", "Salir o no salir?.. He ahí la cuestión...", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE, null)) {
        case 0:
            return;

        case 1:
            break;
    }
    }
    } while (getMenu() != "Salir");

}

public boolean sonLetras(String name) {
    return name.matches("[a-zA-Z]+");
}

public int getMatricula() {
    return matricula;
}

public void setMatricula(int matricula) {
    this.matricula = matricula;
}

public byte getEdad() {
    return edad;
}

public void setEdad(byte edad) {
    if(edad < 0)
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No se aceptan valores menores a    0", "Error", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE, null);
    this.edad = edad;
}

public float getAltura() {
    return altura;
}

public void setAltura(float altura) {
    this.altura = altura;
}

public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}

public String getApe_paterno() {
    return ape_paterno;
}

public void setApe_paterno(String ape_paterno) {
    this.ape_paterno = ape_paterno;
}

public String getApe_materno() {
    return ape_materno;
}

public void setApe_materno(String ape_materno) {
    this.ape_materno = ape_materno;
}

public String getCorreo() {
    return correo;
}

public void setCorreo(String correo) {
    this.correo = correo;
}



public int getLength() {
    return length;
}



public void setLength(int length) {
    this.length = length;
}



public boolean isError() {
    return error;
}



public void setError(boolean error) {
    this.error = error;
}


public String getGenero() {
    return genero;
}


public void setGenero(String genero) {
    this.genero = genero;
}


public String getEstadoCivil() {
    return estadoCivil;
}


public void setEstadoCivil(String estadoCivil) {
    this.estadoCivil = estadoCivil;
}

public String getMenu() {
    return menu;
}

public void setMenu(String menu) {
    this.menu = menu;
}

}
```

---

```
package escuela;

import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPopupMenu;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

import org.eclipse.wb.swing.FocusTraversalOnArray;
import java.awt.Window.Type;

public class Correos {

private JFrame frmAgregandoEstudiante;
private JTextField txtUsuario;
private String correoConcatenado = null;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main() {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Correos window = new Correos();
                window.frmAgregandoEstudiante.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the application.
 */
public Correos() {
    initialize();
}

/**
 * Initialize the contents of the frame.
 */
private void initialize() {
    frmAgregandoEstudiante = new JFrame();
    frmAgregandoEstudiante.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
    frmAgregandoEstudiante.setResizable(false);
    frmAgregandoEstudiante.setTitle("Agregando estudiante");
    frmAgregandoEstudiante.setBounds(100, 100, 272, 164);
    frmAgregandoEstudiante.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frmAgregandoEstudiante.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    txtUsuario = new JTextField();
    txtUsuario.setToolTipText("Introduce la primera parte de tu correo");
    txtUsuario.setBounds(10, 48, 104, 30);
    frmAgregandoEstudiante.getContentPane().add(txtUsuario);
    txtUsuario.setColumns(10);

    JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox();
    comboBox.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] {"@gmail.com", "@outlook.com", "@unacar.mx", "@live.com", "@yahoo.com", "@hotmail.com"}));
    comboBox.setBounds(124, 48, 119, 30);
    frmAgregandoEstudiante.getContentPane().add(comboBox);

    JButton btnAgregar = new JButton("Agregar");
    btnAgregar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            String user,mail;
            RegistroEstudiante re = new RegistroEstudiante();

            user = txtUsuario.getText();
            mail = (String) comboBox.getSelectedItem();
            setCorreoConcatenado(user.concat(mail));
            re.setCorreo(getCorreoConcatenado());
            System.out.println("re.setcorreo " + re.getCorreo());


        }
    });
    btnAgregar.setBounds(77, 89, 89, 23);
    frmAgregandoEstudiante.getContentPane().add(btnAgregar);

    JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("Agrega el correo del estudiante");
    lblNewLabel.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 14));
    lblNewLabel.setBounds(10, 11, 207, 27);
    frmAgregandoEstudiante.getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel);
    frmAgregandoEstudiante.getContentPane().setFocusTraversalPolicy(new FocusTraversalOnArray(new Component[]{txtUsuario, comboBox, btnAgregar}));
}
private static void addPopup(Component component, final JPopupMenu popup) {
    component.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            if (e.isPopupTrigger()) {
                showMenu(e);
            }
        }
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            if (e.isPopupTrigger()) {
                showMenu(e);
            }
        }
        private void showMenu(MouseEvent e) {
            popup.show(e.getComponent(), e.getX(), e.getY());
        }
    });
}

public String getCorreoConcatenado() {
    return correoConcatenado;
}

public void setCorreoConcatenado(String correoConcatenado) {
    this.correoConcatenado = correoConcatenado;
}
}
```

Comment: Have you initialized the String correo ?

Comment: @RishabhKumar yes, it is initializedprivate String nombre = null, menu = null, ape_paterno = null, ape_materno = null, correo = null, genero = null, estadoCivil;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling RegistroEstudiante.setCorreo() from Correos.java seems to happen on a different thread (AWT) than the do-while loop (main), thus the correo field is not getting updated. With some Thread.currentThread() calls added to your code the log printout is the following

```
En RegistroEstudiante.java null Thread[main,5,main] //Thread.currentThread() printouts from do-while loop
En RegistroEstudiante.java null Thread[main,5,main]
setcorreo called: ddd@gmail.com Thread[AWT-EventQueue-0,6,main] //Thread.currentThread() printout from setCorreo()
re.setcorreo ddd@gmail.com
En RegistroEstudiante.java null Thread[main,5,main]
En RegistroEstudiante.java null Thread[main,5,main]
```

Comment: Thanks for replying @hammerfest ! But as you can see in your log printout, the problem is not fixed, after you click on the 'Aceptar' button you see setcorreo called: ddd@gmail.com and re.setcorreo: ddd@gmail.com, BUT the next one should be ddd@gmail.com too, in the RegistroEstudiante.java, and that is not the case, it's getting a null string.

Comment: I never said it fixed anything; these are additional log printouts that demonstrate what the problem is. To fix it, I suggest you to consider a general refactoring/reorganizing of your entire code on the first place; as currently it is a hard-to-oversee mess and most probably no one will debug and correct it for you

Comment: I see your point now, @hammerfest ! Thanks for the info, I will look into it